# How to show utf8 character in ZF2 from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, utf-8, zend-framework2

I am developing an application using Zend Framework 2 & mysql as database.
I want to show arabic character in page, but getting some difficulties while showing it on the page.
When I enter arabic character from application, I'm able to see it in browser while fetching.
But not able to see already available content of arabic in database, while I'm able to see it in phpmyadmin, and sqlYog.

In application setting of zf2, I already have set it to use utf-8 as character encoding which is as follows:

```
'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
        ),
    ),
```

I'm not able to find the reason. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My all setting was fine. Problem was that I was using bjyprofiler for development purpose, So this module(bjyprofiler) was overriding the core zf2 settings.
I just added `charset=utf8` in dsn setting of `bjyprofiler` and it worked for me

Here is the updated db setting in `config/autoload/bjyprofiler.local.php`

```
$adapter = new BjyProfiler\Db\Adapter\ProfilingAdapter(array(
        'driver' => 'pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=' . $dbParams['database'] . ';host=' . $dbParams['hostname'] . ';charset=utf8',
        'database' => $dbParams['database'],
        'username' => $dbParams['username'],
        'password' => $dbParams['password'],
        'hostname' => $dbParams['hostname'],
    ));
```

Comment: Nice @Ahmad. I had the same problem and I used the solution :p